# ListView containing CheckBoxList - Selected items not showing as checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview, checkboxlist

I have a `ListView` with an `EditItemTemplate` that calls a method `onItemEditing`.

Within my `ListView` I have a `CheckBoxList` bound using `LINQ`.

In my `onItemEditing` method, I'm trying to check certain `CheckBoxes` if they are present in a look up table that links users with sectors.

However, when I load the `EditItemTemplate` none of the `CheckBoxes` are checked even though I've set them as selected in the `onItemEditing` method.

Here's the Method:

```
protected void onItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    ListView1.DataBind();

    int regId = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)ListView1.Items[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("LblRegId")).Text);
    CheckBoxList cbl = (CheckBoxList) ListView1.Items[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("chkLstSectors");

//test to see if forcing first check box to be selected works - doesn't work
    cbl.Items[0].Selected = true;

    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DaresburyConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("select * from register_sectors where register_id= " + regId, objConn);
    objConn.Open();

    SqlDataReader objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (objReader != null)
    {
        while (objReader.Read())
        {
            ListItem currentCheckBox = cbl.Items.FindByValue(objReader["sector_id"].ToString());
            if (currentCheckBox != null)
            {
                currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Where did you create your control ? On load, on init ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the listView was being bound again after the checkboxlist was bound.

I removed the binding and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not too late with my answer ;)

I have a CheckBoxList in a ListView which should DataBind like the other controls. The value in the database is a calculated value from this enumeration:

```
public enum SiteType
{
    Owner = 1,
    Reseller = 2,
    SubReseller = 4,
    Distributor = 8
    Manufacturer = 16,
    Consumer = 32
}
```

If the value is 24 this means Distributor and Manufacturer (8 + 16).

I added a HiddenField to the EditItem in my ListView for databinding the value:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblSiteTypes" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow"
                DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource4" DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Value" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSiteTypes" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("SiteType") %>' OnDataBinding="hfSiteTypesBnd" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- other data... -->
</EditItemTemplate>
```

The CheckBoxList is filled through another DataSource, which returns a Dictionary object with the data from the enumeration. In code behind I use the OnDataBinding method of the HiddenField for the selection:

```
protected void hfSiteTypesBnd( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    // read the value
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)sender;
    short val = Convert.ToInt16( hf.Value );
    // find the checkboxlist
    CheckBoxList cblSiteTypes = (CheckBoxList)hf.Parent.FindControl( "cblSiteTypes" );
    // clear the selection (may be not needed)
    cblSiteTypes.ClearSelection();
    // for each item
    foreach ( ListItem li in cblSiteTypes.Items )
    {
        // get the value from each item and...
        short v = Convert.ToInt16( li.Value );
        // ...look up whether this value is matching or not
        if ( ( val & v ) == v ) li.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Et voilà!